# remove build dependencies visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, selenium

i download source code of selenium ,  want to modify code and rebuild but, i just want to build for dot net farmework 4.5 i not need other builds, but i cannot remove dependencies, here is image:
[image: Screenshot]
i also try to install dot net 5.0 but it seems not work
with visual studio 2017, also i install net standard 2.1.524, but not appears to be installed, how to remove other dependencies and build only for dot net framework 4.5

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: did you remove additional<TargetFramework> of your project `.csproj` file?